# react img src showing broken image on mobile phones but loads fine on pc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, mobile, src

I am working on a project and am using image src links from amazon.com products. 
When I use the project on my pc (scaling down with dev tools), the images load without issue. But when I load the app on my phone in safari or chrome it shows a broken image?

the link is stored in a psql database and passed through the `product.picture_main` object.

[image: Image link]

```js
const { product } = this.context

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <section className='ItemPage'>
      <img id="itemImg" src={product.picture_main} alt='' />
      <div className='ItemPage_ItemDetails'>
        <h1 id="itemName">{product.product_name}</h1>
        <h3 id="itemRoast">Roast: {product.product_roast}</h3>
        <h3 id="itemOrigin">Origin: {product.origin}</h3>
        <h4 id="itemDetails">{product.details}</h4>
        <h3 id="itemPrice">Price: ${product.price}</h3>
        <div className='ItemPage_addButton'>
          <AddToCartButton product={product} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

the code above shows up fine in chrome and I am setting a width/ height of 200px so I dont know what is causing a broken image.

Comment: If you go into mobile mode in developer tools (ctrl + shift + m) on the computer and shrink it down, does it show up?

Comment: yes it does. Just not on an actual mobile.

Comment: I honestly have no idea. You're not connected to a vpn on your phone, are you?